# Google GDoc - No preview available

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have around 160 gdoc files in my google drive folder named BLOGS.  First, I took backup to a different location in my mac. Actually, I have to transfer to another account. and to do that I tried a lot of ways, as part of that I deleted and replaced in google drive multiple times. Finally, I got a very big problem that my gdoc files not opening it showing No preview available and showing download option.

[image]

Comment: I found a partial solution that, every file download one by one and double click on downloaded file. It opening properly. But it is very time-consuming task because I have 160 files.